# Symfony - How to access the profiles linked to a mandate object in a Many-To-Many association?

Tags: php, symfony, collections, many-to-many, associations

I am trying to load all **Profiles** linked to a **Mandate**, here is my query:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository('KrownDashboardBundle:Mandate');
$mandate = $repository->findByIdWithProfiles($mandateId);
```

The `findByIdWithProfiles()` function is defined in **Mandate** repository:

```
public function findByIdWithProfiles($id){
  $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
      ->select('m', 'p')
      ->leftJoin('m.profiles', 'p')
      ->where('m.id = :id')
      ->setParameter('id', $id)
      ->getQuery();

  return $query->getResult();
}
```

I can see the **Profiles** linked to the **Mandate** with dump():

```
dump ($mandate);
```

[image]

The profiles are in:

```
 $mandate[0]->profiles->collection['elements'];
```

But when I try to `dump ($mandate[0]->profiles->collection['elements'])`, I am getting an error

> Cannot access protected property
>   Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection::$collection

How can I access the **Profiles** from there?

The association between **Mandates** and **Profiles** is defined like that:

```
Class Mandate{
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Profile", inversedBy="mandates", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="lawyers_mandates")
*/
public $profiles;
}

class Profile{
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Mandate", mappedBy="profiles")
*/
private $mandates;
}
```

Comment: Use getters and setters for your properties. I suggest you to make your profile property protected or private also.